# Using Python write to CSV

Tags: python, csv

My objective is to gather all product descriptions from http://turnpikeshoes.com into a CSV, Separated by row. I have been successful getting the descriptions into a text file, and loop through sites for each product but I'm currently stuck on creating a CSV. Please see my code below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import csv

with open('list.csv','wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)


sites = ['TCF00003','TCF00008']

for s in sites:
    adrs = "http://turnpikeshoes.com/shop/" + str(s)
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.get(adrs)
    time.sleep(5)
    LongDsc = driver.find_element_by_class_name("productLongDescription").text
    writer.writerows({LongDsc})

driver.quit()
```

With this code I get an I/O Error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape4-1.py", line 18, in 
    writer.writerows({LongDsc})
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: intend your code 1 step from this line sites = ['TCF00003','TCF00008'] till  the ned and your issue is resolve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open a file like this:

```
with open('list.csv','wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
```

The file is automatically closed once you exit the `with` block.

You probably want to indent the `for` loop so that it is inside the `with`.

Comment: That works!, but the data fills every column and isn't formatted correctly. How can I format the data so that each description will be in 1 cell per row?

Comment: `writerows()` expects to receive a sequence of sequences of data to be written.  For example if you call `writerows([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])`, then `1,2,3` will be written as the first row and `4,5,6` will be written as the second row.  If you call `writerows` with a single sequence, i.e. `writerows('abc')`, then `a` will be written as the first row, `b` will be the second row, and so on.  What is the data format of `LongDsc`?

Comment: The format of LongDsc is just raw text. So I'm guessing to accomplish my goal I will have to format the data stored in LongDsc before passing it into writerows()

Comment: I solved this issue by just placing `LongDsc` into `writerows([[LongDesc]])`